# Windows IOT App Services and Background Tasks

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-iot-core

at the moment I have a Windows IOT headless app that consists in a background task operated by a timer, which sends and receives data through the Serial Port.

Now, I need a headed app also to be able to send commands through the serial port, but as I don't want multiple apps accessing the serial port at the same time, I thought about communicating with the headless app creating an App Service.

My question is: Is it possible to have a background task and an App Service on the same headless App? If so, would it be possible to stop the background task while the App Service is called? Thanks.

Regards,
Carlos

Comment: Not sure if you can stop the background task while app service is running. However, if you want to make them exclusive, one simple thing you can do is to use named mutex or semaphore that are inter-process to do the process synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods.

One is utilizing the feature of SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() API. Because when the serial device is being in use of one process, other processes will get null return value of calling SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() and can't use it until the first process dispose it. You may do it like this:

```
SerialDevice serialPort = null;
private async void SerialDeviceOperation()
{
    var selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
    var device = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

    try
    {
        while (serialPort == null)
        {
            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(device[0].Id);
        }

        // Your code in here

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    // Do something...
    // Write or read data via serial device
    // ...

    // After complete the operation, dispose the device
    serialPort.Dispose();
    serialPort = null;
}
```

Another is utilizing App Service. Your headless app can host an App service and your headed app can call this service. You can put your serial device operation in the App service and whenever your headless or headed app that wants to use the serial device must pend the semaphore in the App service. Thus, you can achieve the goal of protecting the serial device. You can do it like this:

Create the semaphore in your App service:

```
private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1,1);
```

And provide these two APIs to your headless app:

```
public bool pendSemphore()
{
    return semaphore.WaitOne();
}

public void releaseSemphore()
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

In your headless app you need the following code lines:

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

        private void SerialCommunication()
        {
            inventory.pendSemphore();

            // Put your serial device operation here
            // ...

            inventory.releaseSemphore();
        }
```

In your headed app you can use serial device by calling the App service. More information you can reference ["how to create and consume an app service".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, it really helped me.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, it really helped me. I still have some doubts on how to use the semaphore. I have used them in Arduino but here I'm a bit confused. The reason is that for the Serial communications I have a Class with some methods wich connect to the serial port and then keeps listening or sends messages. So far, I create an instance of this class in the StartupTask and use it. Now I need to create another instance in the App Service, which enters in conflict with the first one. Also I don't know how to share the same semaphore between the two tasks. Thanks